# How do I make a popup that warns the user they are going to a different site?

Tags: wordpress

I need a popup solution in Wordpress that I can use on different links that says "This section of the website is under construction. Click to continue to older archive site."

When the user clicks continue, they automatically go to the link clicked.

I have tried Popup maker but I dont know how to implement the "continue" part.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pop up plugin and choose before exit website appear pop up